# MSSQL - Nodejs - Undefined is not a function issue

Tags: sql-server, node.js, protractor

I have been trying to connect to MSSQL database using node module in my protractor tests. I tried both the methods below but each time I am either getting undefined is not a  function or getting cannot read property of "query/execute".

```
Error: [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at exports.config.onPrepare (....\conf\Conf.js:39:28)
```

I have my connection defined in conf.js

```
   var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');
  var mysql = require('../node_modules/mssql');


exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', //desktop



  allScriptsTimeout: 40000,
  baseUrl: 'https://myurl.com/#/',

   // frameworks to use
    frameworks: 'jasmine',

//Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.

  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'chrome'
 // }, {
 //   'browserName': 'firefox'

 //},

 //   {
 //    'browserName': 'internet explorer'


  }],

 // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory.
  specs: [
    '../tests/HomePage.js'
  ],


     onPrepare: function() {
    var sql = require('mssql/');
    var config = {
        server : '*****',
        user : 'myusername',
        password : 'pass',
        database: 'mydb'
    };



    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
        baseDirectory: '/MyDirectory/screenshots'
     }));



 },




  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true
  }

};
```

In my Test, I did the following: test.js

```
    describe ( " page test , function() {


         it('Should add customer', function() {
            blah blah....

            });//This click will create a record in the backend

       // I am attempting to get the record:

       function runQuery() {

  var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {


      var request = new sql.Request(connection); // or: var request = connection.request(); 
      request.query('select top 1 as result from customers', function(err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks 
        console.log("this is the request: " + request);

        console.dir(recordset);
    });

   });

    };
```

Comment: Link your error with lines and what not how are we supposed to know what function is not right unless you give us somewhere to look

Comment: I included mssql connection in Conf file. All I am trying to do is attempting to query in my test. I don't have any user.js file. I have entered all my user name, database, host info in Conf file itself.

Comment: if i comment out sql part then my scripts run without any issues. I updated complete config file in my post

Comment: If you did npm install mssql, then do var mssql = require('mssql'); see if that fixes your problem

Comment: also looking at mssql npm package there is no createConnection function for mssql

Comment: hard to tell from your snippet of code, but is everything "inside" the `it` callback, or is that happening "outside" the `it`?  ("outside" code runs before "inside" code, so things may not happen the order your text implies.)

Comment: I updated the code. Now good thing is the existing scripts runs but I don't think my sql query is getting executed either, When I did         console.log("this is the request: " + request); nothing is being printed as well.

Comment: I used this guide https://github.com/protractor-br/guide but its not working for me. I get Failed: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined when runing browser.connection.query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dqlserver unofficial and it worked pretty well. We use Windows authentication to login to MSSQL studio so use the below.

```
var sql = require('node-sqlserver-unofficial');
var conn_str = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server={your server};Database={your database};Trusted_Connection={Yes}";

sql.open(conn_str, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error opening the connection!");
        return;
    }
    conn.queryRaw("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Employee", function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error running query!");
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            console.log("\n")
            console.log("Record Info: ");
            for (var j = 0; j < results.rows.length; j++) {
                console.log(results.rows[i][j]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Download MSSQL Unofficial package from here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sqlserver-unofficial